# Changing a service name in docker-compose can't be resolved by node-js app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I changed the service name of the redis container, from "redis-server" to "redis". And the problem is that node-js container can't resolve the service name "redis" and the node-js container down automatically because of this problem. When I switch back to service name of redis container from "redis" to "redis-server", two container are up and running and everything works well.

This is Node-js code

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6379
});
client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
    res.send('Number of visits is ' + visits);
    client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 8081');
});
```

This is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
    redis:
        image: 'redis'
    node-app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "4001:8081"
```

Comment: Have you done `docker-compose down`, `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`?

Comment: and also try `docker build . --no-cache`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helped me fix my problem.